# how to build a simple opencv with cuda example when pkg-config seems not to be working

Tags: c++, docker, opencv, pkg-config

I am using a docker container with Opencv build with CUDA support from [here](https://github.com/JulianAssmann/opencv-cuda-docker/tree/master)
The dockerfile I used (with a slight modification in the base) is [this one](https://github.com/JulianAssmann/opencv-cuda-docker/blob/master/ubuntu-20.04/opencv-4.5.3/cuda-11.4.1/Dockerfile)

Now I am trying to check it with a simple example

```
#include <iostream>
#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"
   ​
​
int main (int argc, char* argv[])
{
    //Read Two Images 
    cv::Mat h_img1 = cv::imread("images/cameraman.tif");
    cv::Mat h_img2 = cv::imread("images/circles.png");
    //Create Memory for storing Images on device
    cv::cuda::GpuMat d_result1,d_img1, d_img2;
    cv::Mat h_result1;
    //Upload Images to device     
    d_img1.upload(h_img1);
    d_img2.upload(h_img2);
​
    cv::cuda::add(d_img1,d_img2, d_result1);
    //Download Result back to host
    d_result1.download(h_result1);
    cv::imshow("Image1 ", h_img1);
    cv::imshow("Image2 ", h_img2);
    cv::imshow("Result addition ", h_result1);
    cv::imwrite("images/result_add.png", h_result1);
    cv::waitKey();
    return 0;
}
```

Unfortunately when you search "build example opencv with cuda", the results are how to "build opencv with cuda" and not how to build an example. So I try to build the example with

```
 g++ -std=c++11 -o image_addition one.cpp `pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv`
```

unfortunately this does not work

```
Package opencv was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `opencv.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'opencv' found
one.cpp:2:10: fatal error: opencv2/opencv.hpp: No such file or directory
    2 | #include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

How can I build this example to check the opencv usage?

EDIT1:

The dockerfile I used is

```
FROM nvidia/cuda:11.4.3-devel-ubuntu20.04

ARG DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
ARG OPENCV_VERSION=4.5.3

RUN apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y &&\
    # Install build tools, build dependencies and python
    apt-get install -y \
    python3-pip \
        build-essential \
        cmake \
        git \
        wget \
        unzip \
        yasm \
        pkg-config \
        libswscale-dev \
        libtbb2 \
        libtbb-dev \
        libjpeg-dev \
        libpng-dev \
        libtiff-dev \
        libavformat-dev \
        libpq-dev \
        libxine2-dev \
        libglew-dev \
        libtiff5-dev \
        zlib1g-dev \
        libjpeg-dev \
        libavcodec-dev \
        libavformat-dev \
        libavutil-dev \
        libpostproc-dev \
        libswscale-dev \
        libeigen3-dev \
        libtbb-dev \
        libgtk2.0-dev \
        pkg-config \
        ## Python
        python3-dev \
        python3-numpy \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

RUN cd /opt/ &&\
    # Download and unzip OpenCV and opencv_contrib and delte zip files
    wget https://github.com/opencv/opencv/archive/$OPENCV_VERSION.zip &&\
    unzip $OPENCV_VERSION.zip &&\
    rm $OPENCV_VERSION.zip &&\
    wget https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib/archive/$OPENCV_VERSION.zip &&\
    unzip ${OPENCV_VERSION}.zip &&\
    rm ${OPENCV_VERSION}.zip &&\
    # Create build folder and switch to it
    mkdir /opt/opencv-${OPENCV_VERSION}/build && cd /opt/opencv-${OPENCV_VERSION}/build &&\
    # Cmake configure
    cmake \
        -DOPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=/opt/opencv_contrib-${OPENCV_VERSION}/modules \
        -DWITH_CUDA=ON \
        -DCUDA_ARCH_BIN=7.5,8.0,8.6 \
        -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE \
        # Install path will be /usr/local/lib (lib is implicit)
        -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local \
        .. &&\
    # Make
    make -j"$(nproc)" && \
    # Install to /usr/local/lib
    make install && \
    ldconfig &&\
    # Remove OpenCV sources and build folder
    rm -rf /opt/opencv-${OPENCV_VERSION} && rm -rf /opt/opencv_contrib-${OPENCV_VERSION}
```

the build type seems to be release.

Comment: When you say “I am using a docker container with Opencv” do you mean OpenCV runtime only, or OpenCV runtime and development headers. The former means you can run software which requires OpenCV. the latter means you can compile software yourself. Those two things are not the same

Comment: I added the dockerfile with the way opencv is build. I am assuming it includes development headers. Am I wrong?

Comment: It says [here](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d7/d9f/tutorial_linux_install.html) where the headers and Cmake integration should be installed by default when building from source. Can you find those *or* can you see what the build script did in its log?

Answer (score 0):

The reason that this is not working is that `pkg-config` doesn't find any information for `opencv`.

```
Package opencv was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `opencv.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
```

Unless there is a strong reason not to, why not install OpenCV using `apt-get`?

`Dockerfile`

```
FROM nvidia/cuda:12.3.1-devel-ubuntu22.04

ARG DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive

RUN apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y &&\
    apt-get install -y \
        build-essential \
        pkg-config \
        libswscale-dev \
        libpq-dev \
        libxine2-dev \
        libglew-dev \
        zlib1g-dev \
        libpostproc-dev \
        libswscale-dev \
        libeigen3-dev \
        libtbb-dev \
        libgtk2.0-dev \
        python3-pip \
        python3-dev \
        python3-numpy \
        # Install OpenCV here!
        libopencv-dev \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

WORKDIR /app
```

It's possible that a few of the packages that you were installing are not necessary. I have trimmed out some.

Build and run a container. Use a volume mount to ensure that `one.cpp` shared with container.

```bash
docker build -t opencv-one . && docker run --rm -v $(pwd):/app -it opencv-one
```

Compile.

```bash
g++ -std=c++11 -o image_addition one.cpp `pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv4`
```

Use `opencv4` with `pkg-config` rather than `opencv`.

[image]